# Android, Jsoup: how to sort results by date

Tags: android, jsoup

I have just started learning jsoup, I'm working on simple schedule, and I have following problem. I wish to sort results of table by date (when each item of list consist date, time and title)

sample of html code:

```
<table class="calendar_table calendar_table_agenda">
    <tbody><tr>
            <td class="agenda-date " rowspan="22">
                Pn, 25-05-2015
            </td>
<td class="agenda-time">
    06:30
    -
    07:25 </td>
<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class monday  </td>
      </tr>
            <tr>

<td class="agenda-time">
    06:30
    -
    07:25</td>
<td class="agenda-title ">
     Class monday </td>
   </tr>
       <tr>
<td class="agenda-time">
    07:30
    -
    08:25 </td>
<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class monday </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

<td class="agenda-time">
    07:30
    -
    08:25 </td>

<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class monday 
</td>
    </tr> 
        <tr>
    <td class="agenda-date " rowspan="22">
                Wt, 26-05-2015 </td>
<td class="agenda-time">
    06:30
    -
    07:25
</td>

<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class tuesday </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
<td class="agenda-time">
    06:30
    -
    07:25
</td>

<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class tuesday
</td>
            </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td class="agenda-date current" rowspan="22">
                Śr, 27-05-2015
            </td>
<td class="agenda-time">
    06:30
    -
    07:25 </td>
<td class="agenda-title ">
    Class wensday </td>
        </tr>
```

Following code gives me only  first result (title+ time+ date) of each day not all of them:

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            int index = 0;
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                for (Element table : doc.select("table[class=calendar_table calendar_table_agenda]")) {
                    for (Element row : table.select("tr:gt(0)")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        dateArray = new String[]{pon, wt, sroda, czwt, pt, sb};
                        for (Element date : row.getElementsByClass("agenda-date")){
                        if(date.nextElementSibling()!=null) {
                            Elements classes = row.getElementsByClass("agenda-title");
                            Elements time = row.getElementsByClass("agenda-time");
                            map.put("classes", classes.get(0).text());
                            map.put("time", time.get(0).text());
                            map.put("date", date.text());
                            arraylist.add(map);
                        }
                       }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

What I want to get is:

day first result

day second result

...

day2 first result

day2 second result

...

and I get now

day first result

day2 first result

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

To get all rows, use this CSS selector instead:

```
table.calendar_table.calendar_table_agenda tr:gt(0)
```

You can remove one `for` loop and use the code below:

```
for (Element row : doc.select("table.calendar_table.calendar_table_agenda tr:gt(0)")) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dateArray = new String[]{pon, wt, sroda, czwt, pt, sb};
    for (Element date : row.getElementsByClass("agenda-date")){
        if(date.nextElementSibling()!=null) {
            Elements classes = row.getElementsByClass("agenda-title");
            Elements time = row.getElementsByClass("agenda-time");
            map.put("classes", classes.get(0).text());
            map.put("time", time.get(0).text());
            map.put("date", date.text());
            arraylist.add(map);
        }
    }
}
```